# How to set up attributes in angularjs directive restricted to comments

Tags: angularjs

I've found nice feature in angularjs. Directives can be set to work on comments.

```
{
    ...
    restrict: 'M'
    ...
}
```

This does the trick as it is spoken in the documentation. Usage of this directive is as follows:

```
<!-- directive: my-directive-name -->
```

And it works just fine as long as I don't need to pass arguments to this directive.
Is it possible to set arguments on directive restricted to comment? 
What's the syntax?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
<!-- directive: my-directive-name this is all an argument -->
```

Where everything after the directive name is the value passed into the directive.

```
app.directive('myDirectiveName', function(){
   return {
      restrict: 'M',
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
          alert(attr.myDirectiveName); //alerts "this is all an argument"
      }
   };
});
```

Comment: Yes. HTML comments don't have "attributes" like a regular HTML element would.