# AngularJS - How to use ng-if without HTML element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-if

Is there a way to tell AngularJS not to display the top HTML element which has **ng-if** directive. I want angular to display child content only.

**Angular Code:**

```
    <div ng-if="checked" id="div1">
      <div id="div2">ABC</div>
      <div id="div3">KLM</div>
      <div id="div4">PQR</div>
   </div>
```

**Rendered HTML:**

```
   <div id="div1"> 
      <div id="div2">ABC</div>
      <div id="div3">KLM</div>
      <div id="div4">PQR</div>
   </div>
```

**What I want:**

```
   <div id="div2">ABC</div>
   <div id="div3">KLM</div>
   <div id="div4">PQR</div>
```

Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/9mgTS/. I do not want `#div1` in HTML. I just want `#div2,3,4` if `checked` is `true`.

A possible solution can be adding ng-if to all child elements but I do not want to do this.

Comment: there's no way to tell angular to not output the parent element without creating a directive with custom template. You can use `template:function(el,attrs)` to run some logic based on attributes and return the appropriate html

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125899/how-to-set-up-attributes-in-angularjs-directive-restricted-to-comments and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23012941/angularjs-how-to-close-ng-if-in-comment-block

Comment: In Angular2 (in case anyone arrives here by accident), use ng-container: `<ng-container *ngIf="true">`

Answer (score 59):

There's a currently-undocumented pair of directives, `ng-if-start` and `ng-if-end`, that you can use for this. They behave analogously to the documented [`ng-repeat-start` and `ng-repeat-end`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat#special-repeat-start-and-end-points) directives, and you can see the [unit tests for them](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/291d7c467fba51a9cb89cbeee62202d51fe64b09/test/ng/directive/ngIfSpec.js#L129-L149) if you like.

For example, given the following code:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-if-start="true">a</li>
  <li>b</li>
  <li>c</li>
  <li ng-if-end>d</li>
  <li ng-if-start="false">1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li ng-if-end>4</li>
</ul>
```

the first four `li`s will be shown and the final four `li`s will be hidden.

Here's a live example on CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PqEJYV

There are also `ng-show-start` and `ng-show-end` directives that work exactly the way you would expect them to.

Answer (score 7):

If you are happy to create a custom directive, you can apply the ng-if to the children programmatically and flatten the DOM in the process:

**Directive Code:**

```
.directive('ngBatchIf', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        compile: function (elm, attrs) {
            // After flattening, Angular will still have the first element
            // bound to the old scope, so we create a temporary marker 
            // to store it
            elm.prepend('<div style="display: none"></div>');

            // Flatten (unwrap) the parent
            var children = elm.children();
            elm.replaceWith(children);

            // Add the ng-if to the children
            children.attr('ng-if', attrs.ngBatchIf);

            return {
                post: function postLink(scope, elm) {
                    // Now remove the temporary marker
                    elm.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

**Angular Code:**

```
<div id="div1" ng-batch-if="checked">
    <div id="div2">ABC</div>
    <div id="div3">KLM</div>
    <div id="div4">PQR</div>
</div>
```

**Rendered HTML:**

```
<div id="div2" ng-if="checked">ABC</div>
<div id="div3" ng-if="checked">KLM</div>
<div id="div4" ng-if="checked">PQR</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o166xg0s/4/

Answer (score 0):

Here's an Angular 1.21 solution:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <div ng-iff="checked" id="div1">
        <div id="div2">ABC</div>
        <div id="div3">KLM</div>
        <div id="div4">PQR</div>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="toggleCheck()">Toggle Check</button>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.checked = true;

    $scope.toggleCheck = function () {
        $scope.checked = !$scope.checked;
    };
}).
directive('ngIff', function ($compile) {
    return {
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                    var bindingElem = iElement.attr('ng-iff');
                    var children = iElement.children();

                    angular.forEach(children,function(c){
                        angular.element(c).attr('ng-if',bindingElem);
                    });

                    $compile(children)(scope, function(newElem){
                        iElement.replaceWith(newElem);
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    };
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/czymoco8/).

Answer (score -1):

I dont understand why you dont want to use a parent div, but this would be a good solution if you have +20 divs:

**HTML**

```
   <div ng-repeat="div in divs" ng-if="checked" id="{{div.name}}">{{div.content}}</div>
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.checked = true;
    $scope.divs = {
         {'name': 'div2', content:'ABC'},
         {'name': 'div3', content:'KLM'},
         {'name': 'div4', content:'PQR'}
    }
});
```

Comment: :( . Nah.. This solution is mixing view with the controller. I want to keep these separate.

Comment: One good reason is if you want to hide or show a group of children, but don't want to add in another tag around those children.

Answer (score -1):

Seems to be a old question but I got similar requirement

```
<div ng-if="checked" id="div1">
      <div id="div2">ABC</div>
      <div id="div3">KLM</div>
      <div id="div4">PQR</div>
</div>
```

I managed like this

```
<mytag ng-if="checked" id="div1">
      <div id="div2">ABC</div>
      <div id="div3">KLM</div>
      <div id="div4">PQR</div>
</mytag>
```

where **mytag** is just any name which is not a html element as long as it does not disturb the layout, this works for me

Comment: Could someone explain why this is down voted? And yes. It should be down voted. But no one has said why.

Answer (score -2):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/9mgTS/1/

`div1` is the parent container for `div2,div3,div4`, if you don't want `div1` in the output html use this:-

```
<div ng-app="App">Click me:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" />
    <br/>Show when checked:
    <div class="div2" ng-if="checked">ABC</div>
    <div class="div3" ng-if="checked">KLM</div>
    <div class="div4" ng-if="checked">PQR</div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:-**

### Using angular js and jQuery:-http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/9mgTS/3/

Assign a common class (example `myClass`) to all elements pertaining to that group.

**JS:-**

```
angular.module('App', []);

function myController($scope) {
    $scope.change = function () {
        angular.element(".myClass").toggle();
    };
}
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div ng-app="App" ng-Controller="myController">Click me:
    <input type="checkbox" ng-change="change()" ng-model="checked" ng-init="checked=true" />
    <br/>Show when checked:
    <div id="div2" class="myClass">ABC</div>
    <div id="div3" class="myClass">KLM</div>
    <div id="div4" class="myClass">PQR</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this is not what I am looking for. I do not want to add ng-if to all child elements. Just imagine maintaining 20+ child elements with ng-if. If someone has to change "checked" to "checked2", it has to be done at 20+ places. Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @waqas - Then use a parent div on top of the div's with ng-if `<div ng-if="checked">`

Comment: @waqas Or you can create a arbitary tag `<mylist>` on top of all the divs http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/9mgTS/2/

Comment: IE does not support custom tags. Moreover adding <mylist> does not solves the issue. we still have a parent tag. We want to get rid of parent tag containing ng-if.

Comment: I believe @waqas is looking for something more like you see in decent templating engines, such as {{ if (condition) }} <my html...> {{ end if }}. Sad that Angular doesn't seem to be able to do this. Angular seems to force the user to use HTML elements for pure logic scenarios - which is pretty stupid.