# Angularjs: how to close ng-if in comment block?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-if

`<div ng-if="true">visible</div>` is pretty easy, but since [ngIf](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) can be used even in comments, what would be the closing `</div>` for comment block?

Tried, w/o luck:

```
<!-- ng-if: true -->
....
<!-- ng-if -->
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know where you heard/read that but it's not true. ng-if is a directive that needs to be added as an attribute in an element.

Comment: I don't think you want this tagged `ngif`. "NGif is an open-source tool that creates the ability for .Net to make/read Animated Gifs"

Comment: It's worth noting you can achieve a similar result using `ng-if-start="true"` and `ng-if-end` [see this stack overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29252098/how-to-apply-an-ng-if-or-other-conditional-in-multiple-td-elements-while-kee)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`ng-if` is restricted to `'A'`. so it can be used only as attribute, you can't use in comment Here's the angularjs code for ngIf

```
var ngIfDirective = ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return {
    transclude: 'element',
    priority: 600,
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'A',       // --> This means restricting to Attribute
```

The `restrict` option is typically set to: `'E'`,`'A'`,`'C'`,`'M'`

One of `EACM` restricts the directive to a specific directive declaration style. `If you don't restrict any, the defaults (elements and attributes) are used`.

`E` - Element name (default): `<my-directive></my-directive>`

`A` - Attribute (default): `<div my-directive="exp"></div>`

`C` - Class: `<div class="my-directive: exp;"></div>`

`M` - Comment: `<!-- directive: my-directive exp -->`