# How to apply an ng-if (or other conditional) in multiple <td> elements while keeping it DRY

Tags: html, angularjs

I want to display a number of `<td>` elements based on the same condition. I am currently doing that with multiple, identical, `ng-if` directives, as such:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td> Display unconditionally </td>
    <td> Same here... (imagine more columns) </td>
    ...
    <td ng-if='myCondition'> Display based on condition </td>
    <td ng-if='myCondition'> And the same </td>
    <td ng-if='myCondition'> for plenty of columns </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

While this works one can't help but notice all the repetition. Any ideas on how I could DRY that up?

Comment: following DRY isnt hard n fast, you cant cancel out your requirements coz of that, people also use WET(write everything twice)

Comment: mycondition is same?

Comment: Yes, the conditions are identical.

Comment: @rkon you can use ng-if-start and ng-if-end for such muliptle hide td's

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use  **ng-if-start and ng-if-end**

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td ng-if-start="false" >one</td>
      <td>two</td>
      <td ng-if-end >three</td></td>
      <td>foure</td>
      <td>five</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/M6hWtfV6qsY7q0DvJGtb?p=preview)

Comment: Cool, didn't know about this feature. Since what version is it included in Angular?

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be what I need - will try it out and come to mark this as the correct answer. Did you happen to find any official documentation on that?

Comment: @rkon nopes no official documentation.I found it few days back somewhere i don't remember :-P

Comment: @Anzeo here is the link for you http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2558-using-start-end-directive-ranges-in-angularjs-1-2.htm you can use start and end with your custom directives as well.

Comment: Official docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-multielement- (linked under 'Directive Info' in https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)

Comment: @thomaux the "-start" "-end" syntax is available since version 1.2, apparently.