# Angular 2 Component: How to select an HTML comment

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

In AngularJS (1.x) we can define a directive in an HTML comment:

```
<!-- directive: my-directive-name -->
```

See [How to set up attributes in angularjs directive restricted to comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125899/how-to-set-up-attributes-in-angularjs-directive-restricted-to-comments)

How can I do this in an Angular 2 component selector (there is no `restrict: 'M'` option)?

**Update:** See this SO question [How to remove/replace the angular2 component's selector tag from HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34588933/how-to-remove-replace-the-angular2-components-selector-tag-from-html), it seems that `replace` is also gone...

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in Angular 2. Angular 2 is meant for modern browsers only (support for IE9+), so components are meant to be defined using custom Html elements which works well on all modern browsers.

Comment: This is not possible!? The problem is that I have some components with an HTML template but which are virtual and should not appear in the DOM (i.e. should not create a new tag, because the CSS classes would have a problem)

Comment: use tag selectors

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it within a comment but you should try have a look at templates, specifically `<template>`:

[Template Syntax](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#star-template)

You can use it like this:

```
      `<template ngFor #item [ngForOf]="items" #i="index">
        <option *ngIf="isSelected(item)" [value]="item.value" selected>{{item.label}}</option>
        <option *ngIf="!isSelected(item)" [value]="item.value">{{item.label}}</option>
      `</template>
```

You can use that in the template/HTML of your component. You'll still have to create your component with HTML tags like `<my-component></my-component>` but the `<template>` tags won't render. Might help.